# Find the sum of values of an Employee and its Parent using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider, I have the following class.

```
public class Employee {

private Integer id;
private Integer parentId;
private int value;
}
```

Now I have the following records.

```
    Employee employee1 = new Employee(1, null, 4);
    Employee employee2 = new Employee(2, 1, 4);
    Employee employee3 = new Employee(3, null, 8);
    Employee employee4 = new Employee(4, 1, 3);
    Employee employee5 = new Employee(5, 2, 11);
```

So the `parentId` is the `id` of an *employee* who is the boss of another *employee*.

The question is to find out the ***sum*** of the value of an *employee* and it's parent if it has any, or return the value as it is. So in this case, the result should be.

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 15 |

How to achieve this using java 8 streams? I have tried the following;

```
  Optional<Integer> first = employees.stream().map(a -> {
                int sum = 0;
                employees.stream().map(b -> {
                    if (Objects.equals(a.id, b.parentId)) {
                        sum = sum + a.value + b.value;
                    }else{
                        sum  = sum + a.value;
                    }
                    return sum;
                });
                return sum;
            }
    ).findFirst();
```

But I am getting error with the sum variable that it should be final or effectively final.

Comment: You don't need streams here. You need a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to achieve that is to create a ***map*** which will allow to retrieve the `value` of an `Employee` by its `id`.

Then, in order to combine  the `value` of each `Employee` with its parent's `value`, use the *value* from the ***map*** or `0` if the *parent* is `null`.

Method below generates a *map* with `id` used as a *key* and employee's `value` as a *value*.

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> getEmplValueById(List<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId,
                                      Employee::getValue));
}
```

The following method creates a *map* with `id` used as a *key* and the ***total value*** of an employee as a map's *value*.

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> getEmplSumById(List<Employee> employees,
                                                   Map<Integer, Integer> valueById) {
    return employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId,
                        empl -> empl.getValue() + 
                                valueById.getOrDefault(empl.getParentId(), 0)));
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employees = List.of(
            new Employee(1, null, 4),
            new Employee(2, 1, 4),
            new Employee(3, null, 8),
            new Employee(4, 1, 3),
            new Employee(5, 2, 11));

    Map<Integer, Integer> valueById = getEmplValueById(employees);

    getEmplSumById(employees, valueById)
         .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("ID %d \t value %d\n", k, v));
}
```

**Output**

```
ID 1     value 4
ID 2     value 8
ID 3     value 8
ID 4     value 7
ID 5     value 15
```

Answer (score 0):

By computing only the value of the child and its first parent, you can do it with a simple filter on the list.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final Employee employee1 = new Employee(1, null, 4);
    final Employee employee2 = new Employee(2, 1, 4);
    final Employee employee3 = new Employee(3, null, 8);
    final Employee employee4 = new Employee(4, 1, 3);
    final Employee employee5 = new Employee(5, 2, 11);

    final List<Employee> employees = List.of(employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5);
    final List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> res = employees
            .stream()
            .map(emp -> Pair.of(emp.id,
                            emp.value + employees
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(e -> e.id.intValue() == Optional.ofNullable(emp.parentId).orElse(-1))
                                    .findFirst().map(Employee::getValue)
                                    .orElse(0)
                    )
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    res.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public class Employee {
    public Integer id;
    public Integer parentId;
    public int value;
    public Employee(final Integer id, final Integer parentId, final int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

result :

```
(1,4)
(2,8)
(3,8)
(4,7)
(5,15)
```

NB: the object Pair I used comes from `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`